AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin can't prevent rerendering of child item in ListView
I show 5 DiaryCards which is custom widget that I created in ListView.
And when user scrolls down, 4 items are added more to this list as using setState.
void scrollListener() {
    // if (_totalCurrentPage.value < 5) return;
    if (_pageController.offset <
        (_pageController.position.maxScrollExtent) - scrollOffset) {
      EasyThrottle.throttle("total-page", const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          () {
        _totalCurrentPage.value++;
        _fetchDiaryCardList();
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchDiaryCardList() async {
    if (!mounted) return;
    final list = await ref
        .read(diaryGroupProvider.notifier)
        .fetchTotalDiaries(_totalCurrentPage.value);

    if (!mounted) return;
    if (_totalCurrentPage.value == 1) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        items = list;
        _completeLoading = true;
      });
    } else {
      for (final newItem in list) {
        bool exists = items.any((item) => item!.diaryId == newItem.diaryId);
        if (!exists) {
          setState(() {
            items.add(newItem);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

The problem is this DiaryCard widget uses CachedNetworkImage.
And in case of errorWidget, it flickers when user scrolls down and 4 more items are added with setState.
It is due to re-rendering issue by setState.
So I use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin with DiaryCard Widget, but it has still same.
And I checked that when new items are added, original widget of DiaryCard are still rebuilt.
CachedNetworkImage(
                                      imageUrl: widget.diary.userAvatar,
                                      memCacheWidth: 200,
                                      placeholder: (context, url) {
                                        return Container(
                                          width: 56,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color:
                                                InjicareColor(context: context)
                                                    .secondary50
                                                    .withOpacity(0.05),
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                              28,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
                                        return ColorFiltered(
                                          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                            InjicareColor(context: context)
                                                .secondary50
                                                .withOpacity(isDarkMode(context)
                                                    ? 0.3
                                                    : 0.2),
                                            BlendMode.srcIn,
                                          ),
                                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                            "assets/svg_2/profile-user.svg",
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      fadeInDuration: Duration.zero,
                                      fadeOutDuration: Duration.zero,
                                      placeholderFadeInDuration: Duration.zero,
                                      useOldImageOnUrlChange: true,
                                    )

Why AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin doesn't work?
And how to prevent this effect?

The problem is this DiaryCard widget uses CachedNetworkImage.
And in case of errorWidget, it flickers when user scrolls down and 4 more items are added with setState.
It is due to re-rendering issue by setState.
